# Using XPath Following to get element from XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have an XML like the following

```
<li class="expandSubItem">
    <span class="expandSubLink">Popular Neighborhoods</span>
    <ul class="secondSubNav" style="top:-0.125em;">
        <li class="subItem">
            <a class="subLink" href="/Hotels-g187147-zfn7236765-Paris_Ile_de_France-Hotels.html">Quartier Latin Hotels</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="expandSubItem">
    <span class="expandSubLink">Popular Paris Categories</span>
    <ul class="secondSubNav" style="top:-0.125em;">
        <li class="subItem">
            <a class="subLink" href="/HotelsList-Paris-Cheap-Hotels-zfp10420.html">Paris Cheap Hotels</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to get all links under "Popular Paris Categories". I used something like this `//li//a/@href/following::span[text()='Popular Singapore Categories']`, but it gave no results. Any idea how to get the correct result? Here is the snippet of the python code that I wrote.

```
t_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g187147-Paris_Ile_de_France-Vacations.html'
page = requests.get(t_url, timeout=30)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

links = tree.xpath('//li[span="Popular Paris Categories"]//a/@href')
print links
```

Comment: `//li[span='Popular Paris Categories']/ul/li/a/@href`

Comment: it did not work because "span" and "ul" are at the same level of the xpath.

Comment: Yes, `span` and `ul` are at the same level, and it doesn't matter. See the demo (or try it in any XPath tester you like) : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/3849byFx2

Comment: I am using python to evaluate the xpath. I have included the python code that I wrote.

Comment: Make sure you post HTML that you actually get from `page.content`, not the one you see in browser...

Comment: The full page.content is too long. But the section that I post here is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126399/discussion-between-agus-sanjaya-and-har07).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
//li[normalize-space(span)="Popular Paris Categories"]//a/@href
```

Notice how `normalize-space()` is used to remove trailing space from the `span` content. This is the reason why the XPath I suggested initially in the comment didn't work for your actual HTML.

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is a new line after "Popular Paris Categories". Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
//span[text()='Popular Paris Categories']/following-sibling::ul//a/@href
```

Comment: @AgusSanjaya it should work (see demo at http://xpatheval.apphb.com/8524GG-JA). What environent are you running this in ? (*what xpath engine etc*)